# jQuery show() method not working with blockUI in IE8 or IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, blockui

Title says it all. Works perfectly in any other browser, but in IE8 and IE9, the show() method isn't working...

Here's how the blockUI modal is set up in the code:

```
            $.blockUI({
                uniqueName: 'the-modal-that-will-not-show',
                focusInput: false,
                message: foo_html,
                css: {
                    padding: 0,
                    margin: 0,
                    top: '50%',
                    left: '50%',
                    'margin-top': '50px',
                    'margin-left': '275px',
                    textAlign: 'left',
                    color: '#000',
                    position: 'absolute',
                    width: '530px',
                    'z-index': 2300,
                    left: '0px',
                    top: '10px'
                },
                overlayCSS: {
                    'z-index': 2299,
                    opacity: 0.5
                }
            });
```

And no matter where I put

```
$('#the-modal-that-will-not-show').show()
```

...it just won't show. If I open the Javascript console in IE and actually type that command in, the modal will show up, but in the wrong place and with some of the inputs not formatted correctly.

And the weird thing is that I surrounded the .show() command with alerts that tell me whether the modal is visible. Before the .show() command, it tells me "false," and after it says "true", even though it's not actually appearing on the screen.

I also tried putting all the CSS stuff in quotes, like 'padding': '0', etc. Didn't make a difference.

Thoughts???

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: 1.7. Can't upgrade, either, due to various circumstances that I can't get into.

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue:

The function that contains this modal is called immediately after there's an $.unblockUI command, and IE is executing the code before $.unblockUI is finished. If I put a delay in there, it works fine.

Comment: I'am having same issue but i didnt call unblockUI , but still IE freezes it.